# Construct a OWF using two functions $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: X \rightarrow Y$

Tags: one-way-function

Given two functions f,g we have to construct h; such that h is one way function. Either f or g is a one way function. We don't know which one is a one way function. Both f and g are defined over X-> Y